# Passing chosen column to measure

Tags: powerbi

I have a table

[image]

And as you can see, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` has similar values, therefore the measure I will create for `A` will be repeated for all other columns.
Is it possible to write a measure with not specified column, and the column will be passed via some visual as matrix?

For example I would like to write something like:

`sum_over_count = SUM( X ) / COUNT('Table'[ID])`

and in for example Matrix I would like to put as columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and as rows measures as `sum_over_count`.
[image]

Of course later I would like to create more complex statistics to calculate, therefore changing in Visualizations panel to show values as Average will not help

Comment: Pivot/UnPivot the columns A to E, you can then use one measure on that column and filter the items by the new column, that will some the source column

Answer (score 2):

You need to Unpivot the data. In the Power Query Data Editor, select the A to E columns and select UnPivot, This will give you two new columns, Attribute and Value:

[image]

Create your measure(s), this is a basic example:

```
Measure = SUM('Table'[Value])
```

You can then add it to a matrix visual

[image]

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: after that operation the number of rows will be multiplied by number of columns that I have unpivoted?
That means if I had 100 rows with unique IDs, after unpivoting 5 columns I will have 500 rows and each `ID` will be duplicated five times?
Therefore to count the previous number of rows I will have to do smth like `COUNT(UNIQUE('Table'[ID]))`

Comment: That's right, it will increase the row size as you have outlined, and will have to do some sort of count distinct

Answer (score 1):

You won't get far with cross-tables in Power BI. I'd recommend to unvivot your table in PowerQuery first, which will put all column names A to F in a "Attribute" column and the data in a "Value" column. From there it's straight forward to create a measure like SUM('Table'[Value]) and then simply filter it by the Attribute column. This is how Power BI works.

[image]

The result of this **one measure** would look in a Matrix visual like this:

[image]